# use jquery autocomplete with carousel for preview and selection

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, carousel

I've successfully used jquery autocomplete to display a list of matching images based on user input. The user experience isn't great though due to the number of potential matches - even with fairly prescriptive input.

I've found this example at nokia http://www.nokia.co.uk/support/download-software/device-software-update (I know it's written in flash) which would provide the ideal interface for what I'm trying to achieve.

Does anyone have any pointers for doing this using jquery autocomplete as a starting point? Or better still know of an existing javascript library that provides this functionality?

I'm using the latest release of jquery if that matters.

Thanks,
Dave.

Answer (score 1):

Try out one of the many lazy load image plugins, like this one:

http://www.appelsiini.net/2007/9/lazy-load-images-jquery-plugin

Comment: Thanks karim. The problem isn't loading too many images at once. The problem is that there can be so many results for a search that I need a nice way of scrolling through the results once they've been retrieved. That's what I liked about the nokia approach - once you've narrowed the result set you can then visually scroll through them looking for the correct item.